# CORS issue solution via proxy services or curl

Tags: node.js, cors, access-control, canvas-lms

I'm hitting a major road block while consuming services `POST` from this client who has no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` at all.

I've tried following solutions or are you saying it's not possible at all?

1. Looked into JSONP but that's limited to GET only.
2. Created a service on my domain that can make a request to client domain. Ended up with `{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }`
3. Haven't tested, but can I've it accomplished using node-curl. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-curl

Please advise.

Comment: So, for some clarifying. Who owns that service?
 Also there are no CORS issues, the are service owner issues :)

Comment: :) the client owns the services, basically Canvas LMS API, it's based on oAuth2, https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/index.html Is there a work around in case headers are not present?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?  Is a web page trying to make a request to your service?  Or something else?  Or is your node.js app just trying to make a request to some other host?

Comment: It's my javascript client code trying to make a POST request to their web service and because of lack of access headers, it's failing and I'm trying to workaround using options mentioned above, 1,2,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, why just not add this header? Just one line of code :)

You may run your own server which will forward requests to that service (nginx can easily do that, [take a peek](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)).
In a nutshell:
`frontend app -> your proxy with CORS headers (like nginx) -> api service`

Comment: I believe I'll need more resources and understanding for that, any videos you can recommend to watch

Comment: As same origin policy is based on http headers and "origin" concept - I'd recommend to dive into HTTP and SOP RFC's, very nice article (obsolete, but very informative) - [rf2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616), SOP RFC [rfc6454](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6454) also wiki has some good links for SOP and how bypass it (recommend read them after rfc's) - [sop on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). If you doesn't have enough time - read all links from wiki which will interest you. PS: curl, tcpdump and netcat is nice things for experimenting with http.